# Bootstrap 4 collapsible on hover with multiple items

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have found a few ways to to expose the collapsible accordion function in bootstrap, however I am unable to customise it in a way that only one `panel-collapse` is triggered when hovering the `div.panel-heading > a` element.

I am doing the following:

```
$('div.panel-heading a').hover(function () {
   $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
 }, function() {
   $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
 });
```

}

But whenever I hover over the `a` element all `panel-collapse` elements open and close. How can I isolate each if they are not children of `panel-heading`?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tupira/084z33g5/1/

Comment: Can you write the html structure for the whole panel?

Comment: The problem is that this code $('.panel-collapse') affects every item of class panel-collapse. The solution is to set the parent of item you want to change the visibility to.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it generically? i.e. triggering the actual original bootstrap function? See my fiddle above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('div.panel-heading a').hover(function () {
   $('.panel-collapse', $(this).closest('.panel')).collapse('show');
 }, function() {
   $('.panel-collapse', $(this).closest('.panel')).collapse('hide');
 });
```